# How to inject javascript in an Android WebView via adb

Tags: javascript, android, adb

Is there an adb command which could execute/inject a javascript in currently focused WebView?

Comment: your task is too specific. I think that it's impossible. At least it should be impossible. If it would be possible, then you could inject JS in any app's WebView, which is a security issue itself.

Comment: I see. Thanks, @VladMatvienko. I'm just playing around with adb and see if it could help me with other use cases. But I'm still hoping I could see some other solutions if there is.

Comment: I will still accept an answer even if the said WebView to be manipulated is not the currently focused WebView.